# Wordpress - That page can’t be found

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed and configured on apache server wordpress (I didn't do that, I am not expert on websites). Now I uploaded my php application so root structure looks like this:

...
images
voucher (this is my application)
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-includes

When I input http://address.com/voucher/index.php into browser I got Wordpress error which contains information "Oops! That page can’t be found.". I don't know why is it trying to achieve my voucher catalog "by Wordpress system", maybe should I set some settings (.htacces or smth like this)?

Comment: either the site name or a screenshot would help here

Comment: Ideally the folder should show the pages. I think the .htaccess has rules to redirect all request to the root.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EewebbZd its my .htaccess

Comment: @Lukas post your .htaccess rules.

Comment: Ok I coped with it by removing     <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule> from .htaccess (from laravel directory)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress when installed uses rewrite to redirect all requests to index.php by default. If you have other dirs or files on the server you will have to consider them in your .htaccess rules.

Modify your .htaccess. Here is a sample rules that bypasses wordpress rules for your voucher directory.

```
#only allow the wordpress rules if it is not request /voucher.
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/voucher [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Or you can do your rules this way.

```
#if the request is for the voucher folder, do nothing and display the page
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/voucher [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```